# Drop normalizing, compression, and stick with dynamics processing?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we add a tag for dynamics processing, and drop the normalizing and compression (except for audio codecs)?

Comment: Why the down-vote?  What is wrong with my question?  It's a discussion.  If you disagree with my suggestion, post it as an answer, as BenV and TomWij did.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your question, votes on the meta are often used to show (dis)agreement with what someone wrote. For that reason anything that happens on the meta doesn't have any effect towards your reputation...

Comment: @TomWij, thanks for clearing that up.  I was under the impression they signified a poor or "not useful" question, like on the main sites.  Downvote away!

Comment: Yes, downvoting a question on meta indicates that the voter thinks the question is bad or unclear. Agreeing or disagreeing with a question doesn't tell the asker anything.

Comment: @neilfein, is there documentation on this somewhere?  I'd really like to get a correct answer on this issue.  I checked the FAQ but didn't see it.

Comment: @Brad - This is my opinion based on experience with several SE sites. It seems there's a lot of confusion about this issue across the network. (For example, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42558/149375).) In general, I wouldn't worry about it all that much; except for meta SO, there's no rep on a meta site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't drop any of them for the following reason:

I think a good thumb rule we should use is to try to choose the most generic tag that your question still applies too. If the question is applies to both `normalizing` and `compression` then it could be tagged `dynamics-processing`, if the question only applies to `normalizing` and not to `compression` then the more specific tag `normalizing` would be a better choice...

Answer (score 5):

Most people are going to type "comp…" into the tags field when talking about compression.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda prefer separate tags myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, a question can only have five tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should be generous with allowing lots of tags to begin with and then merge or delete less useful ones later, probably just before coming out of beta. (less useful means that there are too similar to other tags, or so specific that they will only every come up once or twice)

Comment: +1 No question, allowing the community to tag at will is the will of the community in action.  Perhaps makes for a bit more work later, but... not THAT much more :)